# How to make sure results will contain at least one ID?

Tags: mysql, sql, having

The following query is collecting content IDs from a relational table. It is making sure that my result has at least 2 keywords matching.

My problem is that I also have a "hard keyword" (let's say ID 127), meaning I need to make sure that the hard keyword is included as a must. I guess I'd need to modify my `having` clause, but I cannot figure out how.

```sql
select * from `contents__keywords`
where `keyword_id` in (127, 162, 249, 567)
group by `content_id`
having count(distinct `keyword_id`) >= 2
order by `content_id`
desc
limit 4
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Note that your `GROUP BY` clause and `SELECT` list are inconsistent and should result in an error.  I assume that you have simply oversimplified the query for the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a conditional condition:

```
having count(distinct `keyword_id`) >= 2 and
       sum(case when keyword_id = 127 then 1 else 0 end) > 0
```

If you are using MySQL (as the backticks suggest), you can use a shortcut:

```
having count(distinct `keyword_id`) >= 2 and
       sum( keyword_id = 127 ) > 0
```

Comment: Thank you, `sum`, of course... Idk where my mind was.

Comment: No, I actually needed `and`. It seems like it's so far so good, giving back the results I wanted from my table.

Comment: Extremely sorry for my misunderstanding. I got it all wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Though you got a great solution but since I have prepared this I am sharing here.

Schema:

```
 create table contents__keywords (content_id int ,keyword_id int);
 insert into contents__keywords values(100,127);
 insert into contents__keywords values(100,162);
 insert into contents__keywords values(101,249);
 insert into contents__keywords values(102,127);
```

Query:

```
 select content_id,count(distinct keyword_id) keyword_id_count,sum(case when keyword_id=127 then 1 else 0 end)keyword_id102_count
 from contents__keywords 
 where keyword_id in (127, 162, 249, 567)
 group by content_id
 having count(distinct keyword_id)>= 2 or keyword_id102_count>=1
 order by content_id
 desc
 limit 4
```

Output:

| content_id | keyword_id_count | keyword_id102_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 102 | 1 | 1 |
| 100 | 2 | 1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=25211c6020c1711ac958b2c635e713a2)*